# subclassing NSStream

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to subclass NSInputStream and NSOutputStream to keep track of the command I am passing to my server. This way, when I receive a response back from the server, I know which command it was a response to. When I try to set the command string in my subclass, I get an unrecognized selector error.

Subclasses:

PCFInputStream.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface PCFInputStream : NSInputStream
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *command;
@end
```

PCFOutputStream.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface PCFOutputStream : NSOutputStream
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *command;
@end
```

The .m files just have the command property synthesized so I can call setCommand:

Here is the class I am using these in:

```
 //instance vars in my class
 PCFInputStream *inputStream;
 PCFOutputStream *outputStream;


-(void)followClass:(id)sender
{
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef) SERVER_ADDRESS, PORT,     &readStream, &writeStream);
    inputStream = (__bridge_transfer PCFInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (__bridge_transfer PCFOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream setCommand:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,%@",[sender tag], [class classTitle]]];
    [inputStream open];
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"_ADD_CLASS*%@*%@*%@*%@;", [class CRN], deviceToken, [class classLink],[class courseNumber]];
    [outputStream setCommand:str];
    [outputStream open];
}
```

Here is the error I get when it runs the line

```
[inputStream setCommand:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,%@",[sender tag], [class classTitle]]];

-[__NSCFInputStream setCommand:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e691170
2012-12-01 21:56:20.777 PCF[15610:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFInputStream setCommand:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e691170'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3a1b73e7 0x39043963 0x3a1baf31 0x3a1b964d 0x3a111208 0xfa267 0x39585047 0x39584ffb 0x39584fd5 0x3958488b 0x39584d79 0x394a3441 0x3a18c941 0x3a18ac39 0x3a18af93 0x3a0fe23d 0x3a0fe0c9 0x3743733b 0x394ee291 0x100005 0xe7d48)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Can someone suggest a simple solution for me? I tried wrapping a NSStreamInput instance and my  NSString* command into another class, but that doesn't work for my purposes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just cast an `NSInputStream` to a `PCFInputStream`.  The object has to be created as a `PCFInputStream`, and `CFStreamCReatePairWithSocketToHost` doesn't do that.

You can just attach a `command` property to `NSInputStream` in a category by using an [associated object](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html).  Here's the category interface:

```
@interface NSInputStream (PCFCommand)
@property (nonatomic) NSString *pcf_command;
@end
```

You implement it like this:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSInputStream (PCFCommand)

static int kPCFCommandKey;

- (NSString *)pcf_command {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kPCFCommandKey);
}

- (void)setPcf_command:(NSString *)pcf_command {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kPCFCommandKey, [pcf_command copy],
        OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end
```

Comment: Hi, your example is very helpful. I just don't know exactly where to put this declaration..I have never used categories before.

Comment: Choose New > File from the menu bar.  Then choose the Objective-C category from the Cocoa Touch templates.  Name the category `PCFCommand` and make it a category on `NSInputStream`.  You'll need to import `NSInputStream+PCFCommand.h` in any file where you want to access the property.  Repeat for `NSOutputStream`.

Comment: Perfect. I just found this as you typed it out. The method 'objc_getAssociatedObject' is not found. Also the constant 'OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC' does not work either.

Comment: I have edited my answer.  You need to import `<objc/runtime.h>`.

Comment: Lol at you commenting exactly as I am about to say never mind. Haha thanks!

Comment: @robmayoff please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57195022/what-is-replacement-of-cfreadstreamcreateforstreamedhttprequest

Answer (score 1):

`CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost` creates a `CFWriteStream` and a `CFReadStream`. Those are toll-free bridged with `NSOutputStream` and `NSInputStream` respectively. So what you get back is an `NSOutputStream` and an `NSInputStream`. Whether you've declared subclasses of those or not makes no difference; those are the classes that `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost` creates.

If you really can't use wrapping for whatever reason, you'll need to reimplement the Core Foundation function to create your custom subclasses. In practice I'd recommend you just wrap the `NS[Output/Input]Stream` and use `forwardingTargetForSelector:` so that you can supply your wrappers anywhere one of the original objects is acceptable.

Comment: I might have wrapped the classes incorrectly. Do you mind showing me a very simple example? I wrapped them in a NSObject initially

Comment: I couldn't get the wrappers working, but if I did wrap them, in the delegate method handleEvent, how do I get the command sent by the stream..since the handleEvent delegate method gives a NSStream object, not my custom object with the string command in it.