# What is replacement of CFReadStreamCreateForStreamedHTTPRequest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9

In my objective C project i am using

- Segment 1).

```
[(NSInputStream *)CFReadStreamCreateForStreamedHTTPRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, request,(CFReadStreamRef)[self postBodyReadStream]) autorelease]
```

but CFReadStreamCreateForStreamedHTTPRequest is deprecated 
**what can i write alternatively ?**

I tried

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
```

Error throws:-

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'CFHTTPMessageRef' (aka 'struct >__CFHTTPMessage *') to parameter of type 'NSURLRequest * _Nonnull'

- Segment 2).

```
(NSString *)kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost
```

> 'kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost' is deprecated:
>   Haven't found any replacement API.

Answer (score 0):

To use [`dataTaskWithRequest:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession/1410592-datataskwithrequest?language=objc), you need to create an [`NSURLRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest?language=objc), not a `CFHTTPMessageRef`.

As for `kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost`, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28101582/77567) asks “How to programmatically add a proxy to an NSURLSession” and has an answer that looks good to me.

Comment: Rob firstly thanks :) . For Qw1) is there any replacement for `CFReadStreamCreateForStreamedHTTPRequest` ? Qw2).  is `kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost ` & `kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPProxy ` same ?